I am getting error while i am trying to execute my project please anyone help me to solve this problem
i am getting this error.
I am getting http status 404 error while i am trying to execute my project please anyone help me to solve this problem.i am getting the requested resource is not available.
The origin server didn't not find a current representation for the target resource . please solve my problem if any body knows.

This problem cannot be solved unless you get knowing why the server returns 404 error code. It might be any cause that prevents to return the response.
